# ¿Por qué obtengo IndexError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Me piden hacer el código para sacar los números adyacentes de un string, pero de alguna forma me da un error al seleccionar un carácter del string.

Este es el código al que me refiero:

```
cifra ="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

selection=""
anterior=0
actual=0

for i in range(1,len(cifra)+1):
    anterior=int(cifra[i-1])
    actual=int(cifra[i])
    if anterior==actual or anterior==actual+1 or anterior==actual-1:
        selection+=cifra[i]
        if len(selection)==13:
            print(selection)
    else:
        selection=""
```

Comment: Este error IndexError

Comment: ¿Qué significa `len(seleccion) == 13`?

Comment: `if len(selection)==13:` Lo use para imprimir el string de números adyacentes, solo si la cantidad de caracteres dentro de `selection` es igual a 13.

Answer (score 1):

El motivo por el que obtienes un `IndexError` es que `i` itera `range(1, len(cifra) + 1)`.
Eso significa que `i` toma el valor `len(cifra)`.
Cuando ejecutes `cifra[len(cifra)]` obtendrás un error porque el índice del último elemento de `cifra` es `len(cifra) - 1`.

Si quieres iterar elementos de dos en dos y puedes permitirte un Python de versión por lo menos 3.10, te recomiendo usar [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```py
digitos = (int(d) for d in cifra)
for anterior, actual in pairwise(digitos):
```

Si no puedes y necesitas usar los índices para la iteración, bastará con usar:

```py
for i in range(1, len(cifra)):
    anterior = int(cifra[i - 1])
    actual = int(cifra[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Con pocas correcciones tu código sale marchando...

```py
# dado que partimos la iteración de "1", inicializamos con el primer caracter
# de la cadena recibida
selection = cifra[0]
anterior = 0
actual = 0

# como te indicó @Jorge Luis, le quitamos el "+1", para que no se salga de rango
for i in range(1, len(cifra)):
    anterior = int(cifra[i - 1])
    actual = int(cifra[i])
    if anterior == actual or anterior == actual + 1 or anterior == actual - 1:
        selection += cifra[i]

        # acá quite el "if len( selection ) == 13:" porque no le veo sentido
    else:

        # si tenemos más de un carácter, imprimimos
        if len(selection) > 1:
            print(selection)

        # cargamos la letra que no entraba en secuencia para la próxima iteración
        selection = cifra[i]
```

Comment: Déjame recomendarte `if abs(anterior - actual) <= 1:`.

Comment: @JorgeLuis, excelente observación, mil gracias!!